# Android Textview background takes on layout background colour

Tags: android, android-layout, background, android-edittext

I have set the background of a RelativeLayout to the colour black. Unfortunately, all the EditText's within my layout have now also turned black (so that I can't see the text as the text is black). Obviously I could change the text colour, but that's not what I want. I can't work out how to get the EditText's back to the default style.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:background="@color/BLACK" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textAddRecTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="@string/title_add_rec_layout"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/WHITE" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editFirstName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textAddRecTitle"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:ems="14"
        android:hint="@string/first_name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editLastName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editFirstName"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:ems="14"
        android:hint="@string/last_name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editEmail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editLastName"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:ems="14"
        android:hint="@string/email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editPhoneNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editEmail"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:ems="14"
        android:hint="@string/phone_num"
        android:inputType="phone" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editAddress1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editPhoneNumber"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editPhoneNumber"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:ems="14"
        android:hint="@string/address1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTown"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editAddress2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editAddress2"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:ems="14"
        android:hint="@string/town" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editAddress2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editAddress1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editAddress1"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:ems="14"
        android:hint="@string/address2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editCounty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editTown"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTown"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:ems="14"
        android:hint="@string/county" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editPostCode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editCounty"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editCounty"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:ems="14"
        android:hint="@string/postcode" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSaveCustomerInfo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:text="@string/btn_savecustomerinfo" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the background of the `EditText` to `android:background="@color/WHITE"` (or whatever color for that matter)

here is a tip

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listview_background_shape" >

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="4dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="4dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="4dp"
        android:topRightRadius="4dp" />

    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />

    <stroke android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#c3c3c3"/>

</shape>
```

name this file `background_et.xml` and put it in your `drawable` folder

then for your `edittext`

```
android:background="@drawable/background_et"
```

this will change your edittext according to those values in the file, all you have to do is play with those values until you get what you want

Comment: For additional clarification, by default your `EditText` backgrounds are usually set to transparent. If you don't want the black to show through, setting it to the color you want as this answer suggests will fix this.

Comment: exactly, OR make your own styled EditText

Comment: I've tried that, but the edittext style looks different to what the default is. I'd just like it to look like the default edittext.

Comment: the default edittext style is transparent so it will automaticly change according to the parent layout's background, check my updated answer

Comment: Thanks, that looks a bit better. I'll have a play with it and see if I can get it how I want it.